ELF Electromagnetic wave propagation in plasma (ionosphere) - how?
Can an extremely low-frequency electromagnetic wave (below 500 Hz for example) propagate through an ionosphere? The cutoff frequency of Earth-ionosphere waveguide is approximately 1.7 kHz so I understand the waves below this frequency are trapped in this wave-guide. The low-frequency waves can also propagate inside a duct along the magnetic field line, reaching magnetically conjugate places. I was told that a spacecraft can detect a 150 Hz wave if it is above the region where the wave was generated. Does it mean it can propagate a certain distance along the magnetic field line to the spacecraft but not further because of its low frequency (being attenuated)? The plasma frequency of the ionosphere is too high to allow unguided propagation there, right?

Perhaps change the word propagate to tunnel or evanescent decay and then yes, 100s of Hz waves can make it through if pushed hard enough.  Note that when this is done, it's usually only the normal incidence modes that make it anywhere.

Thank you, what do you mean by pushing hard enough?

If you build a big enough transmitter with enough power, you can get through.  However, in general, you are correct that ELF will reflect off the ionosphere or get ducted along it in a waveguide.  I wrote a really superficial answer at: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/17871/13663.  Note that some ELF power has been found to escape from lightning discharges but it's not clear whether that's due to accelerated electrons locally radiating (through an instability) or direct transmission of radio waves.
